# HttpRuntime.Cache settings for Azure?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, caching, memory

I'm using `HttpRuntime.Cache` for memory caching on Azure.

The problem is that the memory goes full - then it hits the 90% percentage limit of Azure, Azure thinks the role is unhealthy and restarts it - bringing the whole site down.

Now I found the **EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit** property and it seems to be set to 98% on Azure, so above the 90% 'unhealthy' limit.

- How can I change this limit on `HttpRuntime.Cache`? The property is readonly.
- It is possible to tweak the Azure auto restart percentage to a bit higher?
- Are there any other recommended settings for using memory cache? Is there another class that I should use? I can find little information in combination with Azure. Most articles talk about a seperate caching service for if the data needs to be consistent across multiple instances.

To be clear: I want memory caching - I don't need a shared caching through i.e. Redis, because the data has not a great need to be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit` by using the `percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit` attribute of the [`cache` Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228248(v=vs.100)) in your web.config

```XML
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <cache percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit="60" />
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

> The `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit` property can be set with the `percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit` attribute of the `cache` Element for caching (ASP.NET Settings Schema) element in the application's configuration file. If the `percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit` attribute is not set, the cache algorithm determines the maximum size of the cache, and the `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit` property is calculated.

You can get more information on the documentation : [Cache.EffectivePercentagePhysicalLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.effectivepercentagephysicalmemorylimit?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

---

The other option is to disable the Azure auto restart mechanism. It is called [Proactive Auto Heal](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/17/Introducing-Proactive-Auto-Heal.html) and you can disable it by setting the `WEBSITE_PROACTIVE_AUTOHEAL_ENABLED` to `False` :

1. Go to portal.azure.com and go to your Web App for which you would like to disable the feature.
2. Under Settings go to Application Settings.
3. Under App Settings add “`WEBSITE_PROACTIVE_AUTOHEAL_ENABLED`” and set it to “`False`”.
4. That’s it! Proactive Auto Heal is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Hi @CyrillDurand, thanks for your answer. Thinks helps already for half of it. I'm still looking for the perfect Azure settings. I.e. only using 60% of your memory feels like a big waste of the other 40%.

Comment: @DirkBoer I added a way to disable the auto restart mechanism